# Water reflectance effect on Sentinel 2 images

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2

I'd like to know what is causing the effect on the water depicted on the following screen (sentinel tile id: S2B_MSIL1C_20190805T144739_N0208_R139_T20PPA_20190805T162922 located near Saint Lucia).
You can see a darker area on water were light seems to be decomposed resulting in heap of pixels of different colors (green, red, blue).
I've checked the [data quality report](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/document-library/-/asset_publisher/Wk0TKajiISaR/content/sentinel-2-data-quality-report-issue-03-may-2016-?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fsentinel.esa.int%2Fweb%2Fsentinel%2Fuser-guides%2Fsentinel-2-msi%2Fdocument-library%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_Wk0TKajiISaR%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1) but this effect was not mentioned.

[image: sentinel2-L1C-T20PPA-20190805]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is not an anomaly at all.
The bright areas are affected by specular reflections between the sun and the sensor.
In the dark area, something is changing the surface of the water, causing the it to not have the specular reflection. This could be a (natural) oil slick, or a break in the wind field, causing the capillary waves to behave differently.

On the illustration below, you can see an example of a different optical sensor showing similar features.

[image: Optical imagery - oil slicks[1]]

For more info on the linked image, see https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=36873

Comment: I think that the oil slick hypothesis may help explain the variation in color within the image, although I think that @mkadunc is correct in that variations in sensor timing may account for the striations.

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure these long, thin streaks are oil slicks from illegal bilge pumping, or rather, 'bilge dumping'.  I stumbled on a video on Youtube that talks about it, on the 'DW Planet A' channel:
"Bilge dumping: The worst pollution you've never heard of".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4nQBVEE4BE

Answer (score 1):

The *"heap of pixels of different colors (green, red, blue)"* is caused by the fact that the different channels of Sentinel-2 MSI are capturing the light reflected by the waves at slightly different times and at a slightly different angles.

Details of the sensor configuration that causes this are available in the [MSI Instrument Technical Guide](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/msi-instrument). Table 2 on the referenced page lists delays for each band, summarized here (listing offset in seconds relative to B02):

```
| B02 | B08 | B03 | B10 | B04 | B05 | B11 | B06 | B07 | B8a | B12 | B01 | B09 |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 0   |0.264|0.527|0.851|1.005|1.269|1.468|1.525|1.790|2.055|2.085|2.314|2.586| seconds
```

Because your RGB image has channels roughly 0.5 s apart, very short reflections (such as those of a glittering ocean) will look like either red, green or blue pixels. Another cause of bright spots on waves could be [foam](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/?lat=21.66404&lng=-158.05434&zoom=16&time=2018-12-05&preset=1_TRUE_COLOR&gainOverride=0.5&datasource=Sentinel-2%20L1C), but that would likely last longer than 0.5 s.

To try and see the temporal component, I extracted separate bands using [EO Browser](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/?lat=13.63617&lng=-61.35246&zoom=15&time=2019-08-05&preset=1_TRUE_COLOR&gainOverride=0.5&datasource=Sentinel-2%20L1C) for the same scene, and I made a gif that shows the time-lapse of the data in the same order as they are observed by the sensor. (I excluded bands 10, 1 and 9 because their poor resolution made the video too jumpy)

[image: Sentinel 2B, 2019-08-05 Saint Lucia, GIF of bands 2,8,3,4,5,11,6,7,8a,12; EU, Contains modified Copernicus Sentinel data 2019, processed with EO Browser]
Sentinel 2B, 2019-08-05 Saint Lucia, GIF of bands 2,8,3,4,5,11,6,7,8a,12
*Credit: EU, Contains modified Copernicus Sentinel data 2019, processed with EO Browser*

Answer (score 0):

As M. Rasmussen said, much of the time, what appears as darker or lighter water areas are indeed caused by different degrees of reflectance, due to a variety of factors.  One of them is water temperature, I suspect, affecting surface tension.  One can sometimes see this effect on calm days, looking at wide bodies of water ( esp. from a high vantage point ), where you will see wide, vein-like, flatter-shinier patches.  You'll even feel the difference, temperature-wise, when swimming through them!  Boat-wakes will also induce those flatter spots, after the water has settled down.

[image]

[image]

Below: A picture of Kauai, Hawaii state, USA.  Notice the dark ocean swath extending from the *leeward* / dry side ( much less effluents ) of the island — leeward: predominant ocean currents and weather-wise, which almost always move from East to West, at that location.

The darker swath may be due to calmer-flatter water caused by less wind on the leeward side; or, by predominant ocean current refracting around the island ( cancelling or adding up surface waves on the leeward-side ); and/or, possibly, by a difference in temperature on the leeward-side affecting surface tension ( maybe from deeper-cooler water being churned upward, to the surface, similar to a boat wake? ).

Characteristically, this altered reflectance swath, on the leeward side of Kauai, is pretty typical, and observable in many images, especially on dates and times when the sun is closer to perpendicular, flatening the land relief, and making the overall ocean water color appears noticeably brighter compared to other times.

Note: In the Kauai photo, there doesn't not appear to be a lot of surf, judging from the lack of big, white breakers near shore, all around; so presumably, this day had calm conditions / not a ton of current ( some days, it's really pounding — at least on one side — and it can clearly be seen from satellite pics ).

[image: Kauai, Hawaii state, USA.]

---

Addendum: I am no scientist, but the fact that the swath appears even darker in infrared might indicate that it is indeed cooler water on the leeward side.

[image]

Also, the fact that there are often clouds right along the edges of the dark swath of water, seems to confirm that it is indeed colder water: the border of which, causing air-thermal activity and condensation, resulting in cloud formation, as seen in these two examples:

[image]

[image]